# Android Thread Classes

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, runnable

I am trying to implement a simple client server app using Android Studio. I understood the Android limits concerning the main UI thread not being able to handle the network code and the thread not being able to reference the main thread.

However, i am not sure which method to use to run network related commands (ie send OutputStream or/and InputStream). I have two generic questions.

1. Should i use a Worker Thread (Runnable or something else) or use AsyncTask?
2. Which one is better and under which circumstance?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class
>   allows performing background operations and publishing results on the
>   UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers. An
>   asynchronous task is defined by a computation that runs on a
>   background thread and whose result is published on the UI thread.
>
> AsyncTask will go through the following 4 stages:
>
> ```
> onPreExecute()
>
> Invoked on the UI thread before the task is executed
>
> doInbackground(Params..)
>
> Invoked on the background thread immediately after onPreExecute() finishes executing.
>
> onProgressUpdate(Progress..)
>
> Invoked on the UI thread after a call to publishProgress(Progress...).
>
> onPostExecute(Result)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

From the `AsyncTask` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.

Whether `AsyncTask` currently re-uses the same background thread (i.e., if it uses a fixed thread pool of size 1) is a bit vague.  It's a question that could be answered by looking into the `AsyncTask` source.  But even if it doesn't *now*, it could in the future.  If you use `AsyncTask`, your code would automatically benefit from future changes and improvements.  This alone is reason enough to use `AsyncTask`, even if you don't need the other conveniences it brings.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Thanks a lot